# Multiple tables differentiating in data only

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tab bar app. Three of the tabs (favourites, bookmarks, top) are a UITableViewControllers, and are using the same table appearance (it's a list of books with author, name, book cover etc.), only with different data. I already have a custom cell in a xib file which I load into the tableView in the controller. What would be the best hierarchy for this?

Should I make a UITableView and inherit from that, or even a shared UITableViewController? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can have a custom `UITableViewController` which uses your `UITableViewCell`. Create classes like: "BookViewController", "NameViewController", and "AuthorViewController" which are subclasses of your custom `UITableViewController`.

Simply put you could just create a `UITableViewController` which you provide with generic methods to grab data and display it. You'd then create instances (or subclasses) of it and pass data into it. You could even have the grab data method be part of init. Doing so you'd have an `initWithData` method and it would be supplied with the data you needed in that tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a different problem with splitting though, it doesn't load the cell style from xib. I will file a new question.